# SQL Server のクエリ通知について

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

SQL Server の機能にクエリ通知というものがあります。
この機能について2点気になることがあります。

[Q1]
クエリ通知は2020年現在において既に枯れたレガシー技術なのでしょうか？
現代においてデータベースの変更を受けて駆動させる手法としては有効ではないのでしょうか？

[Q2]
クエリ通知の機能を C# で利用するために必要な SqlDependency クラスは .NET Coreにはない様ですが、.NET Core で実装可能な類似の技術はありますでしょうか？

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [Q1] 枯れたレガシー技術なのでしょうか？

枯れた が何を意味するか微妙ですが、

[Microsoft SQL Server Service Broker](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-service-broker?view=sql-server-ver15) の 機能を利用した仕組みで、 SQL Server 2008 頃から存在するので十分枯れていると思います。

レガシーを 悪い意味で 古臭いダサいと取るか、安定していると取るかで回答が分かれますが
正しく要件と照らし合わせて設計すれば便利な機能だと思います。

[通知の計画](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms187528(v=sql.105)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) にも書いてある通り、ミリ秒単位の高速な応答は期待できないので
カタログの一覧が更新されたことを通知する用途なら 有効に利用できますが、
更新直後の値をリアルタイムで取得する用途では利用できません。

> [Q2] SqlDependency クラスは .NET Coreにはない

.NET Core 2.1 以降であれば [System.Data.SqlClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SqlClient/) パッケージをインストールすれば利用できます。

PM> `Install-Package System.Data.SqlClient`

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
```System.Data.SqlClient```をインストールしたら```SqlDependency```クラスが使える様になりました。


.NET Coreでは使えないのかと思っていましたが、自分が追加していたのは```Microsoft.Data.SqlClient```で、こちらだとインテリセンスでも反応せず困っていた所存でした。


枯れた、レガシーなの意味ですが、悪い意味で使用したつもりではありませんでした。古い技術もおっしゃる通り使い方次第では安定したものなので私の働くSI業界では導入しやすい技術だと思います。
ですが、古い技術には機能上問題があり、その改善版が出ていたり、また別のアプローチが主流になっていたりするなどの懸念が感じられたので質問した所存でした。


ちなみに、ミリ秒段位での高速な応答には期待できないとのことですが、最近の設計ではそのようなリアルタイム性の問われるシステムではクエリ通知の代わりとしてどの様な代替策があるのでしょうか？ご存知であればご教授お願いいたします。

Comment: WEB 系 だったら SignalR が 簡単で 便利ですね。 または、キャッシュ管理をする WEB サービスを立てて、その中で Mutex 等を使って 読み込みと 更新を交通整理しながら キャッシュを管理したこともあります。（※ キャッシュがクリアされた直後に DBアクセスが集中するので 読み込みは 代表の1つで行い他の読み込みは待たせる）。キャッシュの中の最大値よりも大きなものを毎回、差分で問い合わせする。 等を行った事があります。実現したい 処理に合わせていろいろ考えて実装しています。

Comment: キャッシュ管理をする WEB サービスが変更があったことを通知する（クエリ通知の代わりになる）ということでしょうか？確かに、能動的に通知する仕組みの方がエラー等で取りこぼす不安もなさそうですね。参考になりました。